# pgfplots: grid only for xy-plane in addplot3

Tags: pgfplots

How can I have a grid only for xy-plane using `\addplot3`?

Hints: 
· To draw a grid with loops is clear. 
· If it is important: I need to say `hide z axis`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[zmin=0, zmax=2, 
grid=both,
% hide z axis,
]
\addplot3[variable=\t, mark=*]({t},{t+2},{0}); 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```